# Navigation Hides Menu Icon

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-nav, responsive-navigation

I created a responsive navigation bar, but when it is in mobile view, the headings on the menu are hiding the menu icon when they are shown. Below is a picture of what is happening (I don' have enough reputation to post pictures yet, so there are links), and a code pen. I have tried adding padding and adjusting the float property, but nothing works. Thank you!

Code pen: http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/yarwRO

After Menu Icon is Clicked:

[image]

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a> <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

<ul class="clearfix">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

<li><a href=""><span>About Us</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="principal's_message.html">Principal's Message</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "mission_and_vision.html">Mission and Vision</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "our_history.html">Our History</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "staff_directory.html">Staff Directory</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "links.html">Links</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </li>

<li> <a href=""><span>School Offices</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="attendance_office.html">Attendance</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "main_office.html">Main</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "magnet_office.html">Magnet</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "bridge_office.html">Bridge</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "english_learner's_office.html">EL</a></li>
    <li><a href= "itd_office.html">ITD</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
    <li><a href= "nurse's_office.html">Nurse</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "safety_ofifice.html">Safety</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "plant_manager's_office.html">Plant Manager</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "cafeteria.html">Cafeteria</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "student_store.html">Student Store</a></li> 
      </ul>
      </li>

<li> <a href=""><span>Academics</span></a>
    <ul>
   <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "departments.html">Departments</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</li>

<li> <a href=""><span>Programs</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com" target="new">IB</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "middle_years_programme.html">The Middle Years</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "ste[+a]m_program.html">STE[+a]M</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "performing_arts_program.html">Performing Arts</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "vei-jv.html">VEI-JV</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "gate_sas_program.html">GATE/SAS</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://lacerstars.org/" target="new">LACER</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>

<li> <a href=""><span>Students</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
    <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "dress_code.html">Dress Code</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "cougar_code.html">Cougar Code</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "attendance_policy.html">Attendance Policy</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com/learner-profile.html" target="new">IB Learner Profile</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">Student Handbook</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "map.html">Map</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/site/default.aspx?PageType=3&ModuleInstanceID=1555&ViewID=7B97F7ED-8E5E-4120-848F-A8B4987D588F&RenderLoc=0&FlexDataID=16590&PageID=845" target="new">Food Menu</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "student_store.html">Student Store</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftmiddleschool.org/2015-16yearbook/index.html" target="new">Yearbook</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>

<li> <a href=""><span>Parents</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href= "parent_bulletin.html">Parent Bulletin</a></li>
    <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
    <li><a href= "parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
    <li><a href= "calendar.html">Calendar</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">District Handbook</a></li>
    <li><a href= "school_site_council.html">SSC Council</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "school_decision_making_council.html">SDM Council</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "elac.html">ELAC</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "contact_teachers.html">Contact Teachers</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    box-sizing:border-box;  /** add this **/
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
   background-color: #4484CE;
}
#nav > a {
    display: none;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

/* first level */

    #nav > ul {
    height: 30px; /* 60 */
    background-color: #93C178;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2.5em; /* 60 (24) */
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block ;
    color: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
}

#nav > ul > li:hover > a, #nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a {
    background-color: #F9CF00;
}
/* second level */

    #nav li ul {
    background-color: #93C178;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
                  padding: 0;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul {
    left: -1px;
}
#nav li ul a {
    font-size: 14px; /* 20 */
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #4484CE;
    padding: 0.75em; /* 15 (20) */
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block ;
    color: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    font-size: 14px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
    background:#FCFCFC;
    color: #465C8B;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */ {
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
}

 @media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */ {
html {
    font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
}

#titleBar{
    padding-top: 20px;  
}

#nav {
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: none;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    background-color: #4484CE;
    height: 5.5%;
}
#nav > a {
    width: 5.125em; /* 50 */
    height: 5.125em; /* 50 */
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: #93C178;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
#nav > a:before, #nav > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    top: 35%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    content: '';
}
#nav > a:after {
    top: 60%;
}
#nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type, #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
    display: block;
}
/* first level */

    #nav > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#nav:target > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    height: auto;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */
}
#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4484CE;
}
/* second level */

                #nav li ul {
    position: static;
    padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
    padding-top: 0;
}

#header{
    display: none;  
    background-color: #4484CE;
    height: 100%;
}

marquee {
    display: none;  
    background-color: #4484CE;
    height: 100%;
}

}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 1350px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 1180px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 1000px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 9px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 9px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 9px;    
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 840px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 8px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 8px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 8px;    
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 750px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 7px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 7px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 7px;    
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 640px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to before it is clicked (i can't post more than 2 links at once) [Responsive Navigation Before Icon is Clicked](http://imgur.com/a/oYYcl)

Comment: Add `z-index: 1` to the menu item in case you want to bring it to the fore...

Comment: @kukkuz could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updates:**

Add below code in all your `media query @media` thus this aligns your `burger-menu` at top while using that on `mobile device`.

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 640px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
        #nav > a{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background:#111;
    }

}
```

```css
#nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    box-sizing:border-box;  /** add this **/
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
   background-color: #4484CE;
}
#nav > a {
    display: none;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

/* first level */

    #nav > ul {
    height: 30px; /* 60 */
    background-color: #93C178;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2.5em; /* 60 (24) */
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block ;
    color: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
}

#nav > ul > li:hover > a, #nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a {
    background-color: #F9CF00;
}
/* second level */

    #nav li ul {
    background-color: #93C178;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
                  padding: 0;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul {
    left: -1px;
}
#nav li ul a {
    font-size: 14px; /* 20 */
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #4484CE;
    padding: 0.75em; /* 15 (20) */
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block ;
    color: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    font-size: 14px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
    background:#FCFCFC;
    color: #465C8B;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */ {
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
}

 @media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */ {
html {
    font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
}

#titleBar{
    padding-top: 20px;  
}

#nav {
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: none;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    background-color: #4484CE;
    height: 5.5%;
}
#nav > a {
    width: 5.125em; /* 50 */
    height: 5.125em; /* 50 */
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: #93C178;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
#nav > a:before, #nav > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    top: 35%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    content: '';
}
#nav > a:after {
    top: 60%;
}
#nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type, #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
    display: block;
}
/* first level */

    #nav > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#nav:target > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    height: auto;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */
}
#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4484CE;
}
/* second level */

                #nav li ul {
    position: static;
    padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
    padding-top: 0;
}

#header{
    display: none;  
    background-color: #4484CE;
    height: 100%;
}

marquee {
    display: none;  
    background-color: #4484CE;
    height: 100%;
}

}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 1350px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
    #nav > a{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background:#111;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 1180px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }
        #nav > a{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background:#111;
    }

}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 1000px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 9px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 9px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 9px;    
    }
        #nav > a{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background:#111;
    }

}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 840px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 8px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 8px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 8px;    
    }
        #nav > a{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background:#111;
    }

}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 750px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 7px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 7px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 7px;    
    }
        #nav > a{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background:#111;
    }

}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 640px ) {
     #nav {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
        #nav > a{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:9;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background:#111;
    }

}
```

```html
<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a> <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

<ul class="clearfix">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

<li><a href=""><span>About Us</span></a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="principal's_message.html">Principal's Message</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "mission_and_vision.html">Mission and Vision</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "our_history.html">Our History</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "staff_directory.html">Staff Directory</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "links.html">Links</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </li>
    
<li> <a href=""><span>School Offices</span></a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="attendance_office.html">Attendance</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "main_office.html">Main</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "magnet_office.html">Magnet</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "bridge_office.html">Bridge</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "english_learner's_office.html">EL</a></li>
 <li><a href= "itd_office.html">ITD</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
 <li><a href= "nurse's_office.html">Nurse</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "safety_ofifice.html">Safety</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "plant_manager's_office.html">Plant Manager</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "cafeteria.html">Cafeteria</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "student_store.html">Student Store</a></li> 
      </ul>
      </li>
      
<li> <a href=""><span>Academics</span></a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "departments.html">Departments</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</li>

<li> <a href=""><span>Programs</span></a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com" target="new">IB</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "middle_years_programme.html">The Middle Years</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "ste[+a]m_program.html">STE[+a]M</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "performing_arts_program.html">Performing Arts</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "vei-jv.html">VEI-JV</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "gate_sas_program.html">GATE/SAS</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "http://lacerstars.org/" target="new">LACER</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>

<li> <a href=""><span>Students</span></a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
 <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "dress_code.html">Dress Code</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "cougar_code.html">Cougar Code</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "attendance_policy.html">Attendance Policy</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com/learner-profile.html" target="new">IB Learner Profile</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">Student Handbook</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "map.html">Map</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/site/default.aspx?PageType=3&ModuleInstanceID=1555&ViewID=7B97F7ED-8E5E-4120-848F-A8B4987D588F&RenderLoc=0&FlexDataID=16590&PageID=845" target="new">Food Menu</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "student_store.html">Student Store</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftmiddleschool.org/2015-16yearbook/index.html" target="new">Yearbook</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>

<li> <a href=""><span>Parents</span></a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href= "parent_bulletin.html">Parent Bulletin</a></li>
 <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
 <li><a href= "parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
 <li><a href= "calendar.html">Calendar</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">District Handbook</a></li>
 <li><a href= "school_site_council.html">SSC Council</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "school_decision_making_council.html">SDM Council</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "elac.html">ELAC</a></li> 
 <li><a href= "contact_teachers.html">Contact Teachers</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Citlalipop I have changed your burger-menu color, change that back to default which you had before.

Comment: I'll try that out right now. Will let you know how it works. (and i don't have enough reputation to show my upvotes)

Comment: @Citlalipop no issue regarding up-vote, it's just that at some point some user may have some queries like you had, so at-least at that time they should  go through a right answers.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just letting you know mine won't show. Thank you so much!

Comment: User who did down-vote, could you please explain reason for that, would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
It responsive function in toggle button to toggle menu show or hide in
```

responsive view. In right corner the button or there when click that button

your menu will be show or hide. In mobile view using the margin-top to show

the menu toggle button fully. It's a normal responsive menu function.

Comment: #nav > a should still have a higher z-index.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that too

Comment: @dhaarani what do you mean by it's normal responsive menu function.

Comment: Would it look the same on the desktop (that's the effect I'm going for) if I changed the media query from "only screen" to "all"? Or would that mess things up

Answer (score 1):

Change line 16 to:

```
#nav > a {
display: none;
z-index:99;}
```

Then to make it look better, use the same blue for the menu icon; change line 132 to:

```
background-color: #4484CE;
```

You could go one step further and use the :active or :visited states or utilize Jquery for the is-clicked, is-open, or other states, e.g.

```
#nav > a:active{background-color: #93C178;}
```

Forked and added all that here: http://codepen.io/bobbyfritze/details/WGpmLb/

Comment: I'll try that out right now. Will let you know how it works.

Comment: Any reason why I should change the color to the blue?

Comment: @ Bobby Fritze Thank you so much! Just wondering why I should change it to blue, or if I do, add a border to make it pop more (i don't know, I don't really have an eye for things like this). I just want to know why, and then ask my boss about it and give them your argument. Love the changing color effect!

Comment: @ Bobby Fritze or should i add a border? If so what color?

Comment: I recommended blue just because having it green makes it blend into the list items and look a little glitchy. Maybe use a third color if the brand colors allow for one. I would not recommend border since they end up looking kinda boxy instead of smooth. You might try a CSS drop-shadow and/or change the border-radius of the burger icon so it's not a hard square. But those are just design opinions. Throw in what you like and recommend to your boss why it's good for the UX.